# eclipse cdt relative include path?

Tags: c++, build, g++, eclipse-cdt

Hey all.  I've downloaded and moved the Xerces (v3.1.1) source here:  /usr/include/xerces and I can see the source in the project explorer like this:

MyCppProject

- Binaries
- Includes

  - [...] // some other directories
  - xerces

    - dom
    - [...] // some other directories

And, here's my simple C++ code:

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>

using namespace xercesc;
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try {
      XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  }
  catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
      return 1;
  }
  XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
  return 0;
}
```

And, here's the error that I get (along with others that are caused by this file not being included):

../main.cpp:1:42: error: xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp: No such file or directory

What I don't understand is how the relative paths work in the source file.  When I say type

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
```

where is it looking, if not on the include paths already listed in the project explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you state in your question it looks like your using the folder name 'xercesc' instead of 'xerces' in your include path.

try

```
#include <xerces/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
```

The include directive will look in all of the directories in the include path and try to find the file specified. So if you specified a folder `c:/something/include` in your include path. it would search for `c:/something/include/xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp`.

If your file can't be found then you need to check the include paths being used.

Comment: Oh wow.  I can't believe I missed that.  I appreciate your keen observation of the details.